# Force Office 365 to activate even when PC has incorrect "no internet" status

Tags: windows-10, office365

Office 365 is refusing to activate (or do a full repair) because the computer has an incorrect "no internet" network status. I tried disabling NCSI, but it still said "no internet". I can confirm that I can access both sites listed in the NCIS registry as well, so I'm not sure why this is not working.

I wonder if there is a way to tackle the problem from the other end and get Office 365 to connect to the existing internet. The PC does have internet access.

Comment: Office 365 must communicate with a licensing server every 30 days.  This can either be through the internet or on an intranet by using a KMS.  I am guessing you are not using a VLK or have a properly configured KMS.  The tools [exists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/vlactivation/tools-to-manage-volume-activation-of-office) but they required your an Office VLK.  You should focus on fixing the incorrect internet status.

Comment: The network status of Windows 10 would affect activation of Office 365. I think it's best to repair network icon to display correctly first. Please check whether the following threads could be helpful. [Windows 10 thinks there is no internet connection](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2117295-windows-10-thinks-there-is-no-internet-connection), [False "No Internet Access" keeping Office apps from activating](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2214927-false-no-internet-access-keeping-office-apps-from-activating)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get NSCI to work by running the below fix. After that, Activating 365 was a breeze.

https://purepcs.co.uk/kb/microsoft-connection-test-ncsi-and-office-365/